# How to text indexing and search with python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to read text files from a folder and subfolders and save them to a json file as a dictionary with python. I'm not sure whether the read is already correct but in the search I always get an error message.

here is my indexing code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import glob
import os
import json

basePath = str(sys.argv[1])
allfolder = []
filename = []
fh = []

for files in glob.glob( basePath + '/*.txt' ):
    filename.append(files)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk( basePath ):
    allfolder.append(dirs)

searchfolder = allfolder[0]

for folder in searchfolder:
    for files in glob.glob( basePath + '/' + folder + '/*.txt' ):
          filename.append(files)     

dic = open('index.json',"w")
info = {}

for i in filename:
    fobj = open(i,"r")
    for line in fobj:
        zeile = line.split(" ")
        for a in zeile:
            b = a.strip()
            if b == "":
                break
            dic.write(json.dumps({'wort' : b, 'pfad' : i}, indent=2))
    fobj.close()
dic.close()
```

and my seach code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
import json

dictionary = 'index.json'
search = str(sys.argv[1])

if os.path.isfile(dictionary) == False:
    print('Die Datei wurde nicht gefunden')

json_data=open(dictionary)

data = json.load(json_data)
pprint(data)
json_data.close()
```

and now the error message

```
christoph@Notebook-CSWS:~/System/Blatt4$ python3 sucher.py a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sucher.py", line 15, in <module>
    data = json.load(json_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/json/__init__.py", line 274, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/json/decoder.py", line 355, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 4 column 2 - line 54490 column 2 (char 87 - 1833872)
```

Can any one help me with my problem?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you are creating broken json file.

If you take tool like `jsonlint` and let it check your "index.json" file, you will see the problem in json file format.

Your code, creating the JSON file is using `dic.write` in a loop, so it is appending pieces of JSON string, which are likely to be valid one by one, but not concatenated.

The solutions are:

### Write resulting JSON file in one shot

If you can afford it, create complete dictionary content first in memory (probably in form of a dictionary), and finally, when you have it complete, dump it into json file just once.

Comment: Thanks. Had the wrong approach but after a little work all works!